# flutter_bloc - how can i get value without BlocBuilder?

Tags: flutter

I'm still a beginner with streams and bloc pattern.

I would like to do following:

- Trigger an event.
- Based on the event get back a state with an object
- Store this object as JSON in a database.

All examples are showing, how an object can be displayed in a widget with BlocBuilder. But I don't need to display the value, only get it and store it. I can't figure out how to get the value into a variable.

How can I do that? In the View class I'm dispatching the event, but now I need to know how to get the object in the state back without using BlocBuilder.

Here are the details:

**Bloc**

```
class SchoolBloc extends Bloc<SchoolEvent, SchoolState> {
  final SchoolRepository _schoolRepository;
  StreamSubscription _schoolSubscription;

  SchoolBloc({@required SchoolRepository schoolRepository})
      : assert(schoolRepository != null),
        _schoolRepository = schoolRepository;

  @override
  SchoolState get initialState => SchoolsLoading();

  @override
  Stream<SchoolState> mapEventToState(SchoolEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoadSchool) {
      yield* _mapLoadSchoolToState();

  Stream<SchoolState> _mapLoadSchoolToState(LoadSchool event) async* {
    _schoolSubscription?.cancel();
    _schoolSubscription = _schoolRepository.school(event.id).listen(
      (school) {
        SchoolLoaded(school);
      }
    );
  }
```

**Event**

```
@immutable
abstract class SchoolEvent extends Equatable {
  SchoolEvent([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}
class LoadSchool extends SchoolEvent {
  final String id;

  LoadSchool(this.id) : super([id]);

  @override
  String toString() => 'LoadSchool';
}
```

**State**

```
@immutable
abstract class SchoolState extends Equatable {
  SchoolState([List props = const []]) : super(props);
}

class SchoolLoaded extends SchoolState {
  final School school;

  SchoolLoaded([this.school]) : super([school]);

  @override
  String toString() => 'SchoolLoaded { school: $school}';
}
```

**View**

```
class CourseView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CourseViewState();
}

class _CourseViewState extends State<CourseView> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("this is my init text");

    final _schoolBloc = BlocProvider.of<SchoolBloc>(context);

    _schoolBloc.dispatch(LoadSchool("3kRHuyk20UggHwm4wrUI"));

    // Here I want to get back the school object and save it to a db
  }
```

**Test that fails**

For testing purposes I have done following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:teach_mob/core/blocs/school/school.dart';

class CourseView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CourseViewState();
}

class _CourseViewState extends State<CourseView> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();  
        BlocProvider.of<SchoolBloc>(context)
      .dispatch(LoadSchool("3kRHuyk20UggHwm4wrUI"));  
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<SchoolBloc, SchoolState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        print("BlocListener is triggered");
      },
      child: Text("This is a test")
    );
  }
}
```

The LoadSchool event is triggered. The text in the child attribute of BlocListener is displayed, but the listener function that should print "BlocListener is triggered" is not executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use BlocListener. It is meant to be used for those cases you mention.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Playing with it, and I can see that the event is fired, but the BlocListener isn't triggered. Will test further.

Comment: Looks like the BlocListener will only be fired, if it is triggered over a child widget. But I need to trigger on page load.

Comment: What about placing it at the root of the build method?

Comment: I think you are missing a `yield` right? `yield SchoolLoaded(school);`

Comment: It's in the bloc "mapEventToState method: yield* _mapLoadSchoolToState();. But you are right, the error is located around there. So I need to understand/read in more detail, how state is parsed back.

Comment: I recommend you to take a look at the differences between yield* and yield.  Your yield* is fine. I think you are just missing the yield in SchoolLoaded

Comment: Instead of unsubscribing to the events manually in the `mapEventToState`, you can override the `transformEvents` method with the following code: `return events.switchMap(next);`. This will do the same think  that you did with `stream.cancel()`, but it's much cleaner.